# FFMpeg failing token authorization

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a file that requires authentication for a user outside the system to read. I can curl the file with a JWT token, but FFMpeg throws a 403 error.

This works:
`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <my_token>" <my_filename> --output results`

But this does not:
`ffmpeg -y  -headers "Authorization: Bearer <my_token>" -i <my_filename> -f wav out.wav -v debug`

The debug stack from ffmpeg shows the Authorization header passed.

```
[http @ 0x56019f430160] request: GET <my filename> HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/57.83.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: <my_server>
Icy-MetaData: 1
Authorization: Bearer <my token>

[http @ 0x56019f430160] HTTP error 403 Forbidden
```

I've tried (I think) every possible combination and permutation of input flags, and all without success. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the `curl` command still work if you request ranges (`-r 0-`) and use the same User-Agent as `ffmpeg` (`-A "Lavf/57.83.100"`)?

Comment: It does - I tried the -r and -a flags, as well as key: value pairs behind -H flags.